# Having trouble using "in" function to check for containment of one array in another

Tags: python

The current code is extremely short. If I understand the "in" function correctly, shouldn't the for loop only iterate and return True if both [1,3] is in [1,4,5]? Right now I am getting true for all of my tests. I feel like there is an easy fix to this, I just don't know.

I tried putting an if statement in-between the for and return lines but that still only returned true.

```
def innerOuter(arr1, arr2):
    for arr1 in arr2: 
        return True 
    return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `if one_element in array`

```
def innerOuter(arr1, arr2):
    for x in arr1:
        if x not in arr2:
            return False
    return True

innerOuter([1,3], [1,4,5]) # False
innerOuter([1,4], [1,4,5]) # True
```

Or you can use `set()` to check it

```
def innerOuter(arr1, arr2):
    return set(arr1).issubset(set(arr2))

innerOuter([1,3], [1,4,5]) # False
innerOuter([1,4], [1,4,5]) # True
```

The same:

```
def innerOuter(arr1, arr2):
    return set(arr1) <= set(arr2)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Comment: This worked. I wasn't familiar with "not" as syntax. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current code will return True for each element in arr2, what you're looking for is `if arr1 in arr2:`

Comment: Returns true for the first element; if it was a generator (`yield` instead of `return`) it would do as you said, but the corrected code is right (although `return arr1 in arr2` also works).

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was an oversight on my part. I didn't know about `return arr1 in arr2` either, that's pretty useful to know

Comment: `if [1,4] in [1,4,5]` doesn't work.  `returns [1,4] in [1,4,5]` doesn't work too.